# Retrieve multiple pictures for each place

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

Is there a way to retrieve multiple place photos per place request?

I am able to retrieve the picture for each place that is contained within the place response, is there a way to retrieve multiple pictures per place?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the Places SKU you are using. If you are using Find Place, Nearby Search, or Text Search requests, these can only return a single photo reference per place, when relevant. However, if you use a Place Details request, you can retrieve a no. of photo reference per place. For example:

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&fields=name,photos&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Do keep in mind that you will still have to make separate place [photo requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) for each photo reference.